# What should i expect from "The C Programming Language" 2nd edition(1991). Example inside explaining

Tags: c

I have had this book "The C Programming Language Second Edition" (Spanish Version) for a few years, I recently decided i would give it a shot. It would be my first programming language and yes I know It's not easy for begginers, i like challenges. **Thing is luckily i found a not-working correctly example (see below)**.

The following code is supposed to count and display the count everytime nc is modified. thing is printf is actually not printing anything. Changing EOF to 1  and typing it won't end the program either.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
      long nc;
      nc = 0;
      while(getchar() != EOF)
            ++nc;
            printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

**Question: Should i be aware of any "Recent" changes in C?**. This book is from 1991, 20 years... (wow I'm getting old)

Comment: The program will end normally when then standard input ends. If you run your program without piping or redirecting results to it, it will end when you hit "CTRL+D" on unixes, or CTRL+Z on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cnictuar's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489970/what-should-i-expect-from-the-c-programming-language-2nd-edition1991-example/6489982#6489982) is exactly what that code snippet looks like in my English paperback edition, 17th printing. Maybe the indent got screwed up in the Spanish translation, but it feels like a funny thing to change.

There are a lot of [new features in C99](http://home.datacomm.ch/t_wolf/tw/c/c9x_changes.html), but the ones that I'm really happy about are:

- named initializers:

  ```
  struct {int a, b, c, d;} s =
  { .a = 1, .c = 3, 4, .b = 5};
  ```
- declarations in `for` loops:

  ```
  for (int i; i<foo; i++) { ... }
  ```
- Initializers for auto aggregates can be non-constant expressions:

  ```
  void foo(int n) {
      int arr[n];
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print after each iteration you have to surround the while with brackets.

```
  while(getchar() != EOF)
  {
        ++nc;
        printf("%ld\n", nc);
  }
```

If you want to "break" the while (send EOF) you need CTRL-D or CTRL-Z.

Anyway, if the book doesn't specify brackets, indent it like this:

```
  while(getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
  printf("%ld\n", nc);
```

Comment: Your 'indent it like this' is _exactly_ how it looks in my English Paperback edition (17th printing!). I wonder why/how a Spanish translation would screw up something so basic.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add a few brakets:

```
while(getchar() != EOF) {
    ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

This will print the value of nc each time you type a character.

Comment: Thank you, the book shows it exactly as I typed it, no brackets. hence my question.